# Installing openssl 3: Can't locate Pod/Html.pm in @INC

Tags: openssl, fedora

When building openssl 3 on Fedora, I get the following error:

> Can't locate Pod/Html.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Pod::Html module) (@INC contains: . /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.32 /usr/local/share/perl5/5.32 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at ../openssl/util/mkpod2html.pl line 14.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building OpenSSL3 on Fedora requires `perl-Pod-Html`:

```
yum install perl-Pod-Html
```